# Jquery autocomplete - change the response to <tab> and <enter> keystrokes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a functioning autocomplete box on my site that I want to work like the 'Tags' autocomplete in SO.

#### Desired behavior

After you see a drop-down of suggestions, hitting `tab` or `enter` on the keyboard 'accepts' the highlighted option, adds a space, and moves the focus to the end of the line for entering the next tag.

#### Current behavior

After you get the drop-down, hitting `tab` or `enter` replaces the entire contents of the textbox with the current suggestion, and the cursor selects all the text (instead of inserting a space and pointing at the end of the line).

How can I achieve this response?

---

This is my javascript:

```
$(function() { 
$( "#tags-field" )
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<%= autocomplete_tags_name_questions_url %>",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                alert("Hi!"),
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name, //+ (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                        value: item.name
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
      },
      minLength: 2
  });
});
```

First, the `.bind` part at the top doesn't seem to be working. How do I reconcile the code [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) with the code above?

Comment: @sscirrus: What's the problem you're running into? How isn't the `.bind()` code working?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker it does navigate away from the field when I hit tab on selecting an item.

Comment: @sscirrus: Try using `event.which == ...` instead of `event.keyCode`

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - took me a while but I got there! Thanks Andrew.

Comment: @sscirrus: Great! What ended up being the issue?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - unfortunately I'm not sure what the exact problem was, but it did end up working with the `event.keyCode` variation. I started debugging by adding/substituting sections of the JQuery UI example into my own code but it didn't work. Eventually, I took another route by copying in the entire UI code into my page (which worked), then gradually substituting my requirements into that example. By testing each substitution I was able to get it to where I needed it without any significant problems. Thanks for all your help Andrew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [multiple values demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple).